# how to convert date time if passing null value in date field

Tags: c#, asp.net, type-conversion, nullable

How to store null value and how to insert null values in database?
im getting this error.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
if (taskObj.EstimatedTime == null)
{
    taskObj.EstimatedTime = Convert.ToDateTime(estimateTimeLabel.Text);
}

public DateTime EstimatedTime
{
    set { estimatedTime = value; }
    get { return estimatedTime; }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `estimateTimeLabel.Text` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify in your database that you can allow null for the specific column.

If you already have a database you can run something like:

```
ALTER COLUMN `YourColumn` datetime2() DEFAULT NULL
```

This will allow you to use null in your database.

You also need to convert your datetime in code to a Nullable type. Otherwise .NET comes out with a default date 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM (not very helpful).

There are two ways to do this. I personally recommend the first but it's purely down to coding style.

You can do this by either using the ? operator:

```
 public DateTime? EstimatedTime
{
    set { estimatedTime = value; }
    get { return estimatedTime; }
}
```

Or by the Nullable generic function:

```
public Nullable<DateTime> EstimatedTime
{
    set { estimatedTime = value; }
    get { return estimatedTime; }
}
```

Don't forget to convert your estimatedTime field to a nullable type also (again either by using the ? operator or Nullable.

I hope that helps. If not then leave me a comment and I will do my best to assist you.